# What does "Booting these guys" mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, american-english, slang

I am not native English speaker, but in a conversation with an American guy, I come across this line. I am adding the situation where that guy used this sentence.

He gave me some things to do, I did something and submitted to that guy. For all the tasks he gave this reply. Is this used in a positive or negative context?
"

He gave exactly this sentence

> ***Booting these guys to edition "4" out of edition 3.***

What did he mean by "booting these guys"?

Comment: Not enough context to know. Add some to your question.

Comment: In this context it sounds like a promotion, as if a person is being kicked forward. But usually to give someone *the boot* means to sack (BrEng) or fire (AmEng) somebody (also discharge). Wish I could help more, you need a native American speaker here.

Comment: Someone will answer, just check back later! By the way, what does "edition 3 and 4" mean? Is it to do with software development? Possibly it was a sarcastic, ironic response if there is no edition 4 to speak of. By the man's tone of voice you should understand if it sounded like praise or frustration.

Comment: Yes its about software development

Comment: boot *tr.v.* **3.** *Slang* To discharge unceremoniously. See Synonyms at dismiss. http://www.thefreedictionary.com/boot

Comment: Were you upgrading someone's software to edition 4? It's just a colorful way of saying you kicked / expelled / sent them out of edition 3 and into the upgrade, edition 4, I suspect. (There's also a small chance, instead, that it had something to do with booting up software, which means starting the software. But it doesn't sound quite right for that.)

Answer (score 2):

To **boot** someone **out** of a location (e.g., a bar or saloon) is to expel them forcefully. The image is literally kicking them out, with the boot on the buttocks of the person forced to leave. Here, obviously, the use is metaphorical, but the implication is that version 3 should have been left behind long ago, just as the patron should have known he was unwelcome in the bar.

Answer (score 0):

That phrase doesn't seem to make sense, but I have a couple of guesses.

As Mari-Lou A said, booting can mean being thrown-out of a place or event, but that is usually in the form of "booted him out of", not "booting him up to".  In can also mean being fired, usually in the form of "booted him".  It can also mean a promotion, usually in the form of "booted him up to".

"These guys" can refer to inanimate objects as well as people--a form of personification.  For example, you could refer to stack exchange questions and say "These guys are a lot more difficult to answer that I thought they would be."

If guys is used in that sense, booting might refer to starting a computer, a shortening of the word "bootstrapping".  Or it might mean upgrading, a variation on the promotion usage, particularity if it was "from" instead of "out of".

However, without more information, these are all guesses--but perhaps still useful information.